# Get the text of the selected item in a WPF listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a data bound listbox in a WPF control.  All I want is the text of the selected index.  If I use SelectedItem.ToString I get the key and text.  If I use SelectedValue.ToString I get just the key.

A few forums have suggested casting like below but that doesn't seem to be working.

```
InputName nameInput = new InputName((ListBoxItem)LbContractors.SelectedItem.ToString()));
```

This is how I am binding the control.  Is that messing it up.

```
LbContractors.ItemsSource = myDictionary;
LbContractors.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
LbContractors.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
```

Comment: If you can get the key, why not just get the value out of the dictionary?

Comment: At that point the dictionary is out of scope.  I load in the items from a SQL database.  I use the dictionary as a temporary holder.  I suppose I could make the dictionary stick around but why can't I simply grab the text like I did in winform.

Comment: Well LbContractors still has a copy of it since it needs it so you could always grab it from LbContractors.ItemsSource. Though there is probably a better solution, this is just one way

Comment: If you are going to discard the dictionary then why not just bind a List<String> in the first place

Answer (score 8):

This should do the trick.

```
(LbContractors.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem).Content.ToString();
```

**UPDATE**

Or try to do this. Convert to Nullable KeyValuePair and get the Value.

```
var kvp = (KeyValuePair<string, object>?) LbContractors.SelectedItem);
if(kvp != null && kvp.Value != null) {
    string selectedText = kvp.Value.ToString();
}
```

In one line with null checking :)

```
string selectedText = ((KeyValuePair<string, object>?) LbContractors.SelectedItem)?.Value?.ToString();
```

Comment: When I use that I get a null reference exception.  Is there somewhere special I have to use that call.  Right now I am trying it in a OnClick raised event for a context menu.

Answer (score 0):

> why can't I simply grab the text like I did in winform

One can if the object is properly de-referenced....

> All I want is the text of the selected index.

But what should the `ToString()` text of a Key Value Pair struct return as per your example? Do you have `ToString()` overloaded?

**Two Issues to Resolve**

1. Are you sure that the SelectedItem is not null? Check for that condition before accessing.
2. One should cast to the appropriate structure (a KVP) instead of blindly calling `ToString()` and *reference* the appropriate property of either `Key` or `Value`.

---

Otherwise here are examples. The first is a listbox bound to a dictionary

```
myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    {"Alpha", "The First Letter"},
                    {"Beta", "The Second Letter"},
                    {"Omega", "Omega Letter"},
                };
```

As the user selects each item, the key and value are show in textboxes below the listbox:

[image]

**Xaml**

```
<ListBox  Name="lbDictionary"
          ItemsSource="{Binding myDictionary}"
          SelectedValuePath="Key"
          DisplayMemberPath="Value"/>
```

And the access to them in textboxes (*I don't show the labels of "Key" and "Value" for brevity*)

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Key, ElementName=lbDictionary}"/>
...
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Value, ElementName=lbDictionary}"/>
```

Hence to access in code behind for `Key` is as such, `Value` would be the same:

```
if (lbDictionary.SelectedItem != null)
    MessageBox.Show(((KeyValuePair<string, string>) (lbDictionary.SelectedItem)).Key);
else
    MessageBox.Show("Select something");
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not use `LblContractors.Text;` if that's all you're looking for?